# Git push does not work

Tags: git, github

Hi I am new to Git and try to create a local repository and committed the code but when I am trying to push the code on my  push command it give this error

```
    SUMITs-Mac-mini:gitupload sumit$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/sumittiwari87/First-Gulp-Lesson.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sumittiwari87/First-Gulp-Lesson.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I have tried to pull the commit changes and agin I get the error.

```
 SUMITs-Mac-mini:gitupload sumit$ git pull origin master
    warning: no common commits
    remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
    remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
    From https://github.com/sumittiwari87/First-Gulp-Lesson
     * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
     * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
    Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
    See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
    fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I do not understand why it is happening.

Comment: If I had to guess, then I'd check that you added the correct remote url

Answer (score 1):

> `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

Your branches do not have a common base commit for history.  This behavior was allowed by default but was typically not the intended result (different commits).

You could do have `--allow-unrelated-histories` when you do your merge (a pull is just a fetch + merge by default, could be configured to do a rebase).  But usually that's not intended, especially you being new to git (unless you are aware of this behavior and history).

My recommendation would be to look at what your local and remote histories are for this repository: `git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph`.  Feel free to editor your question showing the output of this if you would like assistance in interpreting the output.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried some more R&D and found that whenever I create a new repository with readme file , it do a commit which is not matching to my local commit and conflict arises. I create a new repository without readme and finally push my code to github. Wow !

Comment: @s_k_t yep that's correct.  Even GitHub is subject to the same git rules of committing changes to the repo, so that's essentially what adding the readme does.  Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried git pull and solve your conflicts (if any) and then

```
git add .  
git commit -m "comment"
git push origin master
```

?

Answer (score -1):

git pull -u origin master. i could do it as well.
you didn't put -u

Comment: This makes no difference. It's just whether you want to set the tracking or not.